# Backbone is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone.js with require.js. I tried one tutorial and this is my index.html :

```
<script src="app/script/libs/require/require.js" data-main="app/script/main" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app/script/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    var appRouter = new AppRouter(); // Router initialization
    Backbone.history.start(); // Backbone start
  });
</script>
```

And this is main.js :

```
require.config({
  urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone'
  }
});
require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
  function ($, _, Backbone) {
    console.log("Test output");
    console.log("$: " + typeof $);
    console.log("_: " + typeof _);
    console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
  }
);
```

And this is my console:

```
ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
[Break On This Error]   
$(document).ready(function()


ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error]   
$(document).ready(function()

Test output
$: function
_: function
Backbone: object
```

Require.js is working, but the backbone and jquery is undefined, I don't know what's wrong with them.

This is the structure of my file :

[image]
Any idea please. Thanks

Comment: I'd say `require.js` **isn't** working. Try loading  `jQuery` and `Backbone` directly and see if that works. If it does, `require.js` isn't loading them properly. Are you sure the files are where you told `require.js` to look for them?

Comment: @MikeW : I added the structure of my file.

Comment: @MikeW If I load jquery and backbone directly, it works well but I don't really know, what's wrong with my require.js.

Comment: That's a nice picture. I'd guess the paths you've set up for `require.js` are wrong. As always, when you have a problem, simplify. Start by eliminating `require.js` from the problem and load your libraries directly. When that works think about whether you even need `require.js`, and if you do, add it back in after checking your configuration thoroughly.

Comment: I updated the structure of my require.js but it still doesn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should also declare your libs  in [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

```
require.config({
  urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone'
  },
  shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
  function ($, _, Backbone) {
    console.log("Test output");
    console.log("$: " + typeof $);
    console.log("_: " + typeof _);
    console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With your setup you can use Backbone only if it was injected as a dependency in a requireJS module, it is not available in the global name space. Also requiring something that you need in most of every module like jquery, Backbone or underscore seems not the best idea. Just load them as script tag before your requireJS main file and everything is fine.

If you want to keep the shim solution you have to start your app inside a the main.js file

```
require.config({
  urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone'
  }
});

require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone"],
  function ($, _, Backbone) {
    console.log("Test output");
    console.log("$: " + typeof $);
    console.log("_: " + typeof _);
    console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var appRouter = new AppRouter(); // Router initialization
      Backbone.history.start(); // Backbone start
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: I still get this error `ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({`.